# Clearstatcache: what is the point of caching file info?

Tags: php, caching, filesystems, fileinfo

As we know, return values of `file_exists()`, `filesize()` etc. functions are cached by PHP, causing considerable annoyance to developers. I often see and hear advices like "you must place `clearstatcache()` before your file info calls" or "write your own `real_filesize()` and place `clearstatcache()` at the first line". I have seen a lot of code filled with a lot of `clearstatcache()` calls. Additionally, it is not possible to clear the cache per file, you must clear the whole cache every time.

A real software either a) requests for file information rarely, or b) needs always fresh information. If someone really need for caching, they can easily implement it with a little bit of coding.

So, currently I can only see the downside of this caching. I think, filestat caching is one of the major broken things in PHP, and it is included in PHP7 too. The question is to the one who knows: what are the benefits of caching file informations in this unusable way?

Comment: In many other cases, directory/file information is static, and may be accessed frequently, so caching it does save disk i/o which is an "expensive" operation

Comment: This may be of interest but seems to be about another cache so doesn't answer your question: http://jpauli.github.io/2014/06/30/realpath-cache.html